# Why does "rails new my_app" initialize a git repository?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git-init

When I run the Ruby on Rails command `rails new my_app`, it creates the new `my_app` directory, and it contains a `.git` subdirectory, i.e., `./my_app/.git`, so it's apparently doing a `git init`.  Where is that `git init` command coming from, and why does it do that?

Rails version: 7.0.4.3
Ruby version: 3.0.1.p64

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Automatic initialization of a `Git` repo when creating a new app started in [`Ruby on Rails 5.1`](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/5_1_release_notes.html). The `--skip-git` option can be provided when creating a new app to stop `git_init` from happening. When the change was introduced the `git_init` command occurred in the [`app_generator.rb`](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/27632/commits/8989a5057b6dc0e287a8b27ded31f08c5e56d0a7#diff-4521b0667f0d930737cfa0a1ced7dd5c00a15909503123cf3752a6c6ebfcca04) file. In the latest version of ruby on rails (**v7.0.4.3**), the `git_init` command occurs in the [`app_base.rb`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/0b5505e826e2757c73dc84e2de44d5394fd926a1/railties/lib/rails/generators/app_base.rb#L725) file.